# message generation error, ambigious overload of operator <<

Tags: omnet++

I get the following error after generating the message .cc and header files with nedtool/omnet(4.6)

> ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ and ‘const std::basic_string’) CurrentNeighboursMessage_m.cc

That's the message class: CurrentNeighboursMessage.msg

```
cplusplus {{
 #include  <vector>
 #include <string>

 typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVector;
}}

    class noncobject StringVector;

    packet CurrentNeighboursMessage {
        StringVector currentNeighbours;
    }
```

The corresponding code to the error in the generated CurrentNeighboursMessage_m.cc:

error in this line:

> out << *it;

```
  // operator<< for std::vector<T>
    template<typename T, typename A>
    inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<T,A>& vec)
    {
        out.put('{');
        for(typename std::vector<T,A>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
        {
            if (it != vec.begin()) {
                out.put(','); out.put(' ');
            }

            out << *it; 
        }
        out.put('}');

        char buf[32];
        sprintf(buf, " (size=%u)", (unsigned int)vec.size());
        out.write(buf, strlen(buf));
        return out;
    }
```

Does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution at : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/omnetpp/9Cw6F6ws_pc/isW42Rh0WG4J

either don't use typedefs or use this workaround:

```
cplusplus {{
#include  <vector>
#include <string>
//workaround
typedef std::string MyString;

inline std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const MyString & s) {
        std::operator<<(os, s);        
        return os;
}
typedef std::vector<MyString> StringVector;

}}
class noncobject StringVector;
packet CurrentNeighboursMessage {
    StringVector currentNeighbours;
}
```